# I can't change error message in my project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a Laravel 8 project. I want to change magic auth error message. And I did updated my code like this.

`'This code has already been used'` I replaced this message with this in the context of the code `'You will get a link in your email inbox every time you need to log in or register. Keep in mind that each link can only be used once.'`

**OLD AuthController.php**

```
public function magicauth(Request $request)
{
    $auth = app('firebase.auth');

    $email = $request->email;
    $oobCode = $request->oobCode;

    $exits = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    if(!is_null($exits))
    {
        if(is_null($exits->firebaseUserId))
        {
            $fUser = $auth->createUser([
                'email' => $exits->email,
                'emailVerified' => true,
                'displayName' => $exits->name,
                'password' => ($exits->email . $exits->id),
            ]);
            $firebaseID = $fUser->uid;

            $exits->update([
                'firebaseUserId' => $firebaseID
            ]);
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        $result = $auth->signInWithEmailAndOobCode($email, $oobCode);
 
        $firebaseID = $result->firebaseUserId();            
        $user = User::where('firebaseUserId', $firebaseID)->first();
        if(is_null($user))
        {
            return view('auth.messages', ['message' => 'User not found']);
        }

        if($user->role_id != 3)
        {
            return view('auth.messages', ['message' => 'User is not creator']);
        }

        Auth::login($user); 

        return redirect()->route('home');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return view('auth.messages', ['message' => 'This code has already been used.']);
    }

    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

**NEW AuthController.php**

```
public function magicauth(Request $request)
{
    $auth = app('firebase.auth');

    $email = $request->email;
    $oobCode = $request->oobCode;

    $exits = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    if(!is_null($exits))
    {
        if(is_null($exits->firebaseUserId))
        {
            $fUser = $auth->createUser([
                'email' => $exits->email,
                'emailVerified' => true,
                'displayName' => $exits->name,
                'password' => ($exits->email . $exits->id),
            ]);
            $firebaseID = $fUser->uid;

            $exits->update([
                'firebaseUserId' => $firebaseID
            ]);
        }
    }

    try 
    {
        $result = $auth->signInWithEmailAndOobCode($email, $oobCode);
 
        $firebaseID = $result->firebaseUserId();            
        $user = User::where('firebaseUserId', $firebaseID)->first();
        if(is_null($user))
        {
            return view('auth.messages', ['message' => 'User not found']);
        }

        if($user->role_id != 3)
        {
            return view('auth.messages', ['message' => 'User is not creator']);
        }

        Auth::login($user); 

        return redirect()->route('home');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return view('auth.messages', ['message' => 'You will get a link in your email inbox every time you need to log in or register. Keep in mind that each link can only be used once.']);
    }

    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

But when I try now, I see that the message has not changed. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps:

1. If you haven't done it yet, delete or rename the old AuthController class, use only new one, with new message.
2. Make sure routes going to the methods in the new controller
3. Run `composer dump-autoload`.

If the problem still persist I'd check whether some kind of cache mechanism is enabled in php, like opcache.

Comment: Hi @miguner, did you see my suggestions?